# numpy's complex128 conversion

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list of np.complex128 numbers but for all the numbers the complex part is equal to zero. How can I extract the real part of the number (which is pretty much the only part of the number)?

As a side not, I want to do scipy integration but I am not sure whether their integration methods can handle y samples with dtype of np.complex128.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your list is a NumPy array, you can simply refer to its `real` attribute:

```
In [59]: a = np.array([1+0j, 2+0j, -1+0j])
In [60]: a
Out[60]: array([ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j, -1.+0.j])

In [61]: a.real
Out[61]: array([ 1.,  2., -1.])
```

If your list is a Python `list`, perhaps the following list comprehension would be the simplest way to get the real parts you want:

```
In [64]: l
Out[64]: [(1+0j), (2+0j), (-1+0j)]
In [67]: [c.real for c in l]
Out[67]: [1.0, 2.0, -1.0]
```

You would need to do this conversion if you want to integrate a function returning a `np.complex128` with `quad`: `scipy.integrate.quad` expects the function to return some kind of float.

Comment: My list only has one element, can I access the list and then do `c.real`?

Comment: like `c=l[0]` and then `c=c.real`.. will that give me a c which is a float?

Comment: Sure, or you can just do `l[0].real` if `l` is a list with a single complex  number element.